# Run python script in Jupyter Notebook and get access to variable in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to run a python script in jupyter notebook and get access to variables in jupyter.

I tried:

```
!python test.py
```

I correctly get the output of the script, but after it finishes, i cant get access to variables in test.py.

Then i tried:

```
%load test.py
```

It loads the script into jupyter, but it fails due to dependency problems (and it´s very uncomfortable because the file is very large)

So is it possible to run a python script like !python and keep the variables in jupyter for further processing?

Comment: Why doesn't `import test` solve your problem? I don't get the use case

Comment: in test.py there is loading / preprocessing of a dataset, i want so visualize the dataset with jupyter, so after running test.py i want to get access to train_set in juypter.

Comment: If you `import test`, the dataset variable should be available too as `test.train_set`

Comment: it displays "module 'preprocess' has no attribute 'x_train'" because i think the script has first to be running and loading the data.

Comment: You probably ought to display your folder structure. You shouldn't need magics or shell access. Simple import works fine in Jupyter.